# phpunit - can name of testsuite be the same as existing class?

Tags: php, unit-testing, class, phpunit, test-suite

I created a suite of php scripts, which perform a number of 'Memcached' operations, and I have written phpunit tests for this suite. The name of the test suite is `Memcached`, and the `phpunit.xml.dist` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Memcached">
            <directory>./test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

However, when I run this test suite with the `--testsuite=Memcached` flag, I receive the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Class "Memcached" does not extend PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.
```

The error presumably occurs because php already has a class called `Memcached`.

If I rename the testsuite to `MemcachedTest` in the XML file, and run the tests with the `--testsuite=MemcachedTest` flag, the unit tests run and complete with zero errors.

I would rather name the test suite `Memcached`, as this would match the formatting of our other test suites.

Can test suites for 'phpunit' be named the same as an existing class?

Comment: How are your test case classes named?

Comment: Test case classes have the name of the class with a `Test` appended. For example: `MemcachedTest`, `ParserTest`, and so on. Even without any unit tests in the suite, the suite still fails due to the suite being named `Memcached`.

Comment: I just tried with PHPUnit 6.5.5 and everything works as expected. There must be something wrong in your setup or environment. I suggest you try to create a simple project that would reproduce your problem and publish it so others could see if they can reproduce the problem too. To answer your question "Can test suites for 'phpunit' be named the same as an existing class?" - yes, there's no connection between classes and test suite names.

Comment: When you tried on your server, is \Memcached a valid class name?

Comment: I didn't have Memcached. After installing the extension, indeed i could confirm your issue is legit. I just posted an answer explaining why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Can test suites for 'phpunit' be named the same as an existing class?

**Yes**, but only if the class is a test suite implementation.

Otherwise, **no**.

The reason why you're running into this issue is:

> If the test suite name is a name of an existing class, the class will be instantiated as a test suite.

`Memcached` is obviously not a PHPUnit test suite.

On the other hand:

> If the test suite is just a string, an empty `TestSuite` object will be created with the given name.

To solve your issue, give the test suite a name that's not a class name:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Memcached Tests">
            <directory>./test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

The behaviour you've experienced is actually [documented in the `PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite` class](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/8df998c18b6498d9be2383fec8556be16d2bced9/src/Framework/TestSuite.php#L107-L121):

```php
/**
 * Constructs a new TestSuite:
 *
 *   - PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite() constructs an empty TestSuite.
 *
 *   - PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite(ReflectionClass) constructs a
 *     TestSuite from the given class.
 *
 *   - PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite(ReflectionClass, String)
 *     constructs a TestSuite from the given class with the given
 *     name.
 *
 *   - PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite(String) either constructs a
 *     TestSuite from the given class (if the passed string is the
 *     name of an existing class) or constructs an empty TestSuite
 *     with the given name.
 *
 * @param mixed  $theClass
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this; I appreciate the answer. I wish we could name our test suites the same as an existing class to be consistent with our other suites, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

Your test classes need to extend `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` class

```
<?php
/**
 * Class SomeTest.
 */
class SomeTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        // test case
    }
}
```

See the doc https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: My test classes do extend `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`